# How to connect a socket with android using wifi direct

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, serversocket, wifi-direct

I am trying to connect to a socket from the client to the server using wifi direct so I have this code on the server:

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2009);
 Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

and I have this code on the client

```
final WifiP2pDevice peer = wifiP2pDeviceList.get("aMacAddress");
          WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                            config.deviceAddress=peer.deviceAddress;
                            mManager.connect(mChannel,config,new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    mManager.requestGroupInfo(mChannel,new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {

                                            try {
                                                Socket socket = new Socket();

                                                int port = 2009;

                                                int timeout = 5000;
                                                socket.bind(null);

                                                socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(peer.deviceAddress, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT); // Error here
                                        }
                                            catch (IOException e){

                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
```

Can I directly use the MAC address or what is my other solution ?

Comment: The MAC address of which device?

Answer (score 1):

Socket communication needs InetAddress instead of deviceAddress string.

```
socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(address, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
```

You can get the groupOwnerAddress (you can get only this IP address from WIFIP2P), after connection.

```
mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
        InetAddress address = wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress;
        //socket communication
    }
});
```

All devices can get this address. Send a message to this address, and groupOwner can get your IP, from the socket.